# Storing GUI Values Into an Array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface

Given my converter program, how can I store the binary output into an array and then output it onto the screen? Currently it just outputs the converted number but I need to store it into an array first. I have not implemented arrays outside of console programs yet so I'm not entirely sure on how to attempt this yet.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.InputMethodListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class NumberConverter extends JPanel {
    private JLabel binaryLabel = new JLabel();
    private JLabel totalone = new JLabel();
    private JLabel totaltwo = new JLabel();
    private JLabel decimalLabel = new JLabel();
    private JTextField  hexdecString = new JTextField();
    private JButton convert;

    public NumberConverter() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        JLabel converterName = new JLabel("Hexadecimal Input");  

        convert = new JButton ("Convert");

        convert.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());
        add (convert);

        JPanel panelName = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        panelName.add(converterName);
        panelName.add(hexdecString);
        add(panelName, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel totalPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,3));
        totalPanel.add(new JLabel("Binary:"));
        totalone = new JLabel("---- ---- ---- ---- ----");
        totalPanel.add(totalone);
        totalPanel.add(binaryLabel);

        JPanel totalPanel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,3));
        totalPanel2.add(new JLabel("Decimal:"));
        totaltwo = new JLabel("------");
        totalPanel2.add(totaltwo);
        totalPanel2.add(decimalLabel);

        JPanel south = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        south.add(totalPanel);
        south.add(totalPanel2);
        add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }        

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){       
            Integer n = Integer.valueOf(hexdecString.getText(), 16);
            decimalLabel.setText(String.valueOf(n));
            binaryLabel.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(n));     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more clearly what you mean when you say you have to store the binary output into an array? binary output of what? Why do you need it in an array?

Comment: Whichever the converted hexadecimal number is, I have to store its binary equivalent into an array and then output that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

...

Integer n = Integer.valueOf(hexdecString.getText(), 16);
decimalLabel.setText(String.valueOf(n));

// make an array of characters where each character 
// is a '1' or '0' corresponding to the binary representation of n
char[] charArray = Integer.toBinaryString(n).toCharArray(); 
binaryLabel.setText(Arrays.toString(charArray));
```

Which turns the binary string array into a binary char array. This is no better than what you had, mind you, only seems to correspond to what you're asking for.

Comment: ok, but now how could I go about grouping each binary set of 4 in an array so for example [1001][1010][0010][1000][1111]. Up to 5 arrays

Comment: if this is homework you should tag it as such and seek to learn from the resources of the class. In short, you could use a for loop to extract substrings from the binary string (first indicies 0-3, then 4-7, etc) and put the resulting substrings in a string array.

Comment: It was homework but now i'm just curious. Can you tell me why my Convert button is so big? I can't seem to get it down to a smaller size

Comment: It's probably related to the BorderLayout you're using. You just put that button into the parent jpanel, while you create sublayouts for all the other buttons. See something like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html